# $_POST not working with <select>

Tags: php, html, forms, select, post

I can get the $_POST working perfectly with the inputs but not with the select statements for some reason.  Here is my code:

---

registration.php

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action="results.php" method="post">

     <div class="form-group">
         <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="user_type">Type</label>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <select id="user_type" name='user_type' class="form-control">
                <option selected="" value="<?php if (isset($user_type)) { echo 'admin'; } ?>">Faculty</option>
                <option value="<?php if (isset($user_type)) { echo 'registeredUser'; } ?>">Student</option>
            </select>
         </div>
     </div>

     <!-- Submit Button -->
     <div class="form-group">
       <div class="col-md-12">
         <button id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block"> <span class="k-icon k-si-plus"></span>Submit</button>
       </div>
     </div>

</form>
```

results.php

```
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
    {
        // Setting the form inputs to variables
        $first_name = trim($_POST["first_name"]);
        $last_name = trim($_POST["last_name"]);
        $email_address = trim($_POST["email_address"]);

        if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $user_type = $_POST['user_type'];
            echo $user_type . '<br><br>';
        }
        echo $first_name . '<br><br>';
        echo $last_name . '<br><br>';
        echo $email_address . '<br><br>';
    }
```

---

**ouput:**

Alex

Cory

alex@mydomain.com

---

Any Ideas as to why this $_POST['user_type']; isn't working?

Comment: Do you have <input type="submit" name="submit" /> in Your HTML? I advice You to do var_dump($_POST); to see what the $_POST actually contains.

Comment: Sure that user_type has any value in the html?

Comment: Well, I did try it without the php inside the values, aka:
<option selected="" value="admin">Faculty</option>
but still no output.

Comment: At a guess I would say that in your registration script the variable $user_type is not set. Since it is not set,  the values of your two options are set to an empty string, which would explain why the variable is empty in results.php. Try using the browser inspector to check that your options actually contain a value.

Comment: Here is a screenshot showing the results from the inspector.  http://imageshack.us/a/img546/631/ujpu.png  The thing that I find odd about the $user_type variables not working is that why would they not work in a <select> statement but work for an <input> statement?

Comment: The screenshot sides not tell us anything.  The issue appears to be in `registration.php`.  You have a conditional check in each `<option>` tag to check if the `$user_data` variable is set.  Try either removing these checks (E.g. `<option selected="selected" value="admin">Faculty</option>`), or adding `<?php $user_type = true; ?>` at the top of the `registration.php` script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that what you have posted is the complete contents of `registration.php` then the issue is that your value for each of the `user_name` options contains an empty string.

The actual HTML that your script generates is:

```
<select id="user_type" name='user_type' class="form-control">
    <option selected="" value="">Faculty</option>
    <option value="">Student</option>
</select>
```

This is happening because your `registration.php` script is checking if the PHP variable `$user_data` is set before adding the values of `admin` or `registeredUser` to the `<option>` tags.

If we expand your code you can see that the `if` condition will never fire:

```
<option selected="" value="<?php 
    if (isset($user_type)) {
        // This will never be fired because the PHP variable $user_data is not set.
        echo 'admin'; 
    } 
    // The result is that nothing is echoed so the HTML reads value=""
 ?>">Faculty</option>
```

To fix, then either remove the conditional check:

```
<select id="user_type" name='user_type' class="form-control">
    <option selected="selected" value="admin">Faculty</option>
    <option value="registeredUser">Student</option>
</select>
```

Or set `$user_data` at the start of the script:

```
<?php $user_data = true; ?>
<form class="form-horizontal" action="results.php" method="post">

   <div class="form-group">
   ...
```

But what I think you are really trying to achieve is to determine which of these options to populate as selected in your form.  If this is the case, you should check that `$user_type` is set and if it's value matches the option value, mark that option as selected.

```
<select id="user_type" name='user_type' class="form-control">
    <option <?php 
                if (isset($user_type) && $user_type === 'admin') {
                    echo 'selected="selected" '; 
                } 
            ?>value="admin">Faculty</option>
    <option <?php 
                if (isset($user_type) && $user_type === 'registeredUser') { 
                    echo 'selected="selected" '; 
                } 
             ?>value="registeredUser">Student</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I cant see the submit button in your code, does it have name='submit' on it ?
Additionally if you are using chrome inspect the post in network(developer tools) to see if 'submit' is posted

Answer (score 0):

This happens because both of your options under `select id="user_type"` have no values when registration.php is executed.

```
<option value="<?php if (isset($user_type)) { echo 'registeredUser'; } ?>">Student</option>
```

If `$user_type` is not defined the value for both options will be `""` (empty string) - and I assume this is what happens.

Comment: So you are suggesting...?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to achieve. You could either define `$user_type` in registration.php (so that `isset($user_type)` will evaluate to `true`) or change the code to have some fallback values for those options, such as: `<option value="<?php echo isset($user_type) ? 'registeredUser' : 'default-value-goes-here' ; ?>">`

Comment: Nice translation of my comment into an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

## **Here's the Answer**

The problem had a little to do with PHP and also a little to do with HTML.  PassKit did a great job explaining the PHP which I ended up using in my code to make it work properly. Look to his answer about the PHP and mine about the HTML.

The opening < form > tag needed an "id" attribute that matched the < select > tag's "form" attribute which neither of them had.

## Solution:

```
  <form id="user-form" class="form-horizontal" action="results.php" method="post">
```

right here -^ needed: id="someFormID"

---

```
    <!-- Faculty or Student? DROP-DOWN -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="user_type">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-4">
```

---

```
            <select form="user-form" id="user_type" name='user_type' class="form-control">
```

right here ---------------------^  needed:  form="someFormID"

---

```
                <option <?php 
                            if (isset($user_type) && $user_type === 'admin')
                            {
                                echo 'selected="selected" '; 
                            } 
                        ?>value="admin">Faculty</option>
                <option <?php 
                            if (isset($user_type) && $user_type === 'registeredUser')
                            { 
                                echo 'selected="selected" '; 
                            } 
                        ?>value="registeredUser">Student</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Submit Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <button id="singlebutton" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary center-block"> <span class="k-icon k-si-plus"></span>Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Urmm... if you try your solution without the PHP changes I suggested (that are also included in your answer), you'll find that the solution has NOTHING to do with the omission of form ID.  If you need convincing, then try running the code posted here https://ideone.com/hgaJeI

Comment: Hey man, I didn't put down your answer at all.  All I know, is that when I used your code, WITHOUT THE HTML FORM ID, it continued to not output to the results.php page.  I don't know why you're voting down my answer... Its correct none the less.  So was yours, in terms of PHP. Thank you for your help. I can change some technicalities in the way I said my answer on here if it pleases you. I wasn't saying you were wrong.  I was simply saying what worked for me. Sorry about that!

Comment: I'm not saying that you 'put down' my answer. This site exists to help people in resolving coding problems. The way your answer was written implied that simply adding a Form ID would solve the problem. This is incorrect and hence the down vote and comment to let other users who may stumble upon this question know that the accepted answer will not solve the problem. Try taking your original code from your question and only add an ID to the form - you'll find that it makes absolutely no difference, because your PHP will still write an empty string to the `value` attributes of your `options` tags

Answer (score -1):

use `submit` button in your form or check post with `if($_POST)`